# I have a polygon with 4 corners, not a square. How do I get the latitude and longitude of smaller sections of it in python?

Tags: python, gis

I have a polygon with 4 corners, a GIS projection. It is not an exact square. How do I get the latitude and longitude of smaller sections of it. The grid will be broken into smaller squares (each 500x500 meters, the 2d resulting spread has dmensions of 1728x1984). I need the lat and lon of one corner of each square. I was looking at np.mgrid or np.meshgrid but they do not seem to be able to have the inputs I have. I have 4 points with 2 values each.

```
LL_lat = 52.29427206432812
LL_lon = 4.379082700525593
LR_lat = 52.29427206432812
LR_lon = 18.893280870398133
UL_lat = 60.0
UL_lon = 3.0
UR_lat = 59.827708427801085
UR_lon = 20.735140174892805
```

So I think I need to break open a 2 dimensional array into smaller intervals. How can I do that. The intervals are fixed in spacing.

The polygon on the right is that one that I have. I want a method of finding the lower left corner lat and lon for each of these cubes (they are all the same size).[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SEtd.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my boss helped me figure it out if you all are curious :)

We are converting danish weather data GIS grid from DMI

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import h5py

projection = ""
tmpfile = "file_path"
with h5py.File(tmpfile_in, 'r') as h5file:
    projection = h5file['where'].attrs['projdef'].decode('utf-8')

#projection = '+proj=stere+ellps=WGS84+lat_0=56+lon_0=10.5666+lat_ts=56' 
dmi_proj = Proj(projparams=projection)  # DMI input, custom stereographic projection
wgs_proj = Proj(init='EPSG:4326')  # WGS84

###Lat and lon in corners are known from file
LL_lat = 52.29427206432812
LL_lon = 4.379082700525593

###Get start projections as wgs projections instead of lat and lon (for the `calculation)`
x0, y0 = pyproj.transform(wgs_proj, dmi_proj, LL_lon, LL_lat)
print(x0, y0)
xscale = 500.0 
yscale = 500.0

latitude = []
longitude = []
###Whether or not the j and k orders need to be decending 
### will figure out, but `thats more based on the set up of your datafile.` 
for j in range(0, (1984 -1)):
    print(j)
    for k in range(0, (1728 -1)):
        east = x0 + j*xscale
        north = y0 + k*yscale
        ### convert back to lat and lon
        lon, lat = pyproj.transform(dmi_proj, wgs_proj, east, north)
        longitude.append(lon)
        latitude.append(lat)

print(longitude)
print(latitude)
```